# Toolbar to modify displayed html/content in IE / Firefox / Chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, toolbar

I want to create toolbar, whose functionality would be:

Whenever the toolbar is "On/Activated",  all pages should be parsed by a function, and the modified html should be displayed.

[Example: 
i) There was this skype toolbar that would recognize phone-numbers in pages and automatically add skype links
ii) If you have used MacAfee / Alexa toolbars, they modify the search results page displayed by Google

My functionality would a lot simpler though]

- I want to create this for all browsers (though answers/pointers to any one platform would be appreciated).
- Please note that I am new to toolbar development, so detailed pointers from basics would be very helpful.
- I have heard to GreaseMonkey. However, if I can do it in a more "basic" way, it would be very helpful.  (Alternately, tips to make a "custom" toolbar using GreaseMonkey would be welcome - though I would like to do away with ability to add scripts, etc. Also I installed greasemonkey and it does show up as a toolbar in FF/IE at all! In IE, there is separate executable to add scripts - I want a standalone toolbar with ON/OFF facility in the browser).

Thanks much!
Regards,
JP

Answer (score 0):

For Google Chrome you can create an [Extension](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions) that uses a [content script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) to inspect and modify the page. Extension can be developed in HTML and Javascript so they are very easy to create.  Chrome also [supports](http://blog.chromium.org/2010/02/40000-more-extensions.html) Grease Monkey scripts.

In firefox, Grease monkey scripts are the way to go.

In Internet Explorer, I believe there is a plugin you can install to have support for Grease Monkey scripts, although the liklihood of an IE user having it installed is very low.